# Image Stacking onto eachother onLayout Android

Tags: android, layout

How can i stack images onto eachother?

My problem is that i want the images to stack and i want the second image to be slightly transparent so he background shines partially through.

Can someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a frame layout and put two imageviews ,2nd image will stack on 1st.
now change the transparency of 2nd image like this

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
iv.setAlpha(123);
```